# Why doesnt the onClickListener do anything?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Following a tutorial, I did set up onClick-Listeners before.

Now I am trying to make a simple app for listening to one stream, but my onClickListener doesn't do anything.

I created a new very simple app in android studio 3.3.2 to find out what is happening. I guess it is something very basic.

```java
package com.example.musicplay;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button play_button = findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        Log.i("Button found","this one: " + play_button.getText());

        play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            // The code in this method will be executed when the play button is clicked on.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "A click happened!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/play_button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The toast message should appear when the button is clicked, but nothing happens.

Comment: why you need to have two setContentView ?

Comment: thanks, that was quick ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling setContentView twice.  This will replace the view hierarchy set up by the first call.  Remove the second call to setContentView.